# Batch replacements in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I've learned how to do simple search and replace operations in my MySQL databases using phpMyAdmin...

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = replace(my_column,'Spain','Spanish')
```

I just wondered if there are ways to target more than one fields and/or tables at a time. For example, if you have three tables named One, Two and Three and each one has a field named Article, could you do a search-and-replace operation in all three tables simultaneously? Or could you even search fields with different names, like One.Article, Two.Article, Three.Content?

Solutions don't have to be limited to phpMyAdmin. I'm interested in learning about other popular DB administration programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UPDATE supports multi-table syntax:

```
UPDATE One, Two, Three 
SET One.Article = replace(One.Article,'Spain','Spanish'), 
Two.Article=replace(Two.Article,'Spain','Spanish'), 
Three.Content=replace(Three.Content,'Spain','Spanish');
```